# How to select multiple items in listview android java

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to select multiple items from a listview and when the items are selected they are each given a unique id.

This is my adapter class so far:

```
public class CallDisplay extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private final Context context;
        private final List values;

        public CallDisplay(Context context, List values) {
            super(context, R.layout.product_list, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }




        class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;

            public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                  InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                  mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
          }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, parent, false);
            TextView Name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView Desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView Price = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            TextView ebaylink = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.elink);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.prod_image);
            TextView id = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);

            id.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("id"));
            Name.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("name"));  
            Desc.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("desc"));
            Price.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("price"));
            ebaylink.setText(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("elink"));
            new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(((HashMap<String, String>)values.get(position)).get("photo"));

            //imageView.setImageBitmap("http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Samsung-Galaxy-6-3-sample-image-3.jpg");

            return rowView;
        }
```

}

How can I edit it so that when multiple items are selected they are each given a unique id number? Thank you

Comment: Do you already have multiple selection working, or do you need to know first how to allow the user to select multiple items, then how to ensure that each item has a unique ID?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ListView.setChoiceMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29) and pass it [`CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE). Then you can call [`getCheckedItemIds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds%28%29).

Your adapter should also implement `getItemId(position)`. If nothing else, you can just return the `position` argument itself, so at least all the items will have different IDs according to the adapter.

Comment: For some reason when I added:
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

it doesn't even mark/highlight items in list. 

Why is that?

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, I don't have enough information to tell you why this might happen.